Why are triangle free connected graphs fragile?
Let $G$ be a graph. A vertex cut set $S \subseteq V(G)$ is called an independent cut if $S$ is  independent. A simple connected graph on at least 3 vertices is called a  fragile graph if it contains an independent cut.
I see the following result from the paper(G. Chen, X. Yu, A note on fragile graph. Discrete Math. 2002,41-43) without proof.
Claim. Every triangle free connected graph with at least 3 vertices is fragile.
But I do not get idea for proving the claim.

In a triangle-free graph, the neighborhood $N(v)$ of any vertex is an independent set. If the graph is connected, then $N(v)$ is an independent cut: it separates $v$ from the rest of the graph.
The exception is for graphs that are stars: in that case, $N(v)$ is the rest of the graph. But then, assuming there are at least $3$ vertices, we can instead delete $v$.

Nice. I forgot the basic thing!

It happens to all of us.
